# Models in Zend Framework

Tags: javascript, zend-framework

I am new to zend framework. I have created "models" folder in application directory. Inside models folder I created a class `Application_Models_Albums` which extends `Zend_Db_Table_Abstract`.

Now when I use the following code in IndexController. I get error:

```
$albums = new Application_Models_Albums();
$this->view->albums = $albums->fetchAll();
```

> Error:  Fatal error: Class 'Application_Models_Albums' not found in
>   H:\Documents\IIS Server
>   Root\localhost\learning\zf1\application\controllers\IndexController.php
>   on line 13

Please help. How can I load models in zend framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your model class name should be `Application_Model_Albums` - with `Model` in singular.
See http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.loader.autoloader-resource.html for more info on Zend Autoloader.

Answer (score 2):

You need to name your model Albums. and save in `models/albums.php`

The auto-loader will figure out where to load it from by the name. so even though the model is named `albums`, you call it by `new Application_Models_Albums()`

The autoloader find it in `application/models/albums.php`

similarly the `Zend_Db_Table_Abstract` class is located in `Zend/Db/Table/Abstract.php`

**edit**

IF you cant get the [autoloader](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.loader.autoloader.html) to work, you can do it the quick and easy way by just adding `models/` to your include path. I've done this before and it works fine.

Something like `set_include_path(get_include_path().PATH_SEPERATOR."models/")` in your index.php

Comment: My class name is Application_Models_Albums and it is located in application/models/albums.php. But still getting error.

Comment: Tale a look at the autoloader documentation. http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.loader.autoloader.html

Answer (score 0):

you need to require your model class-

```
require_once 'PathToModel\Application_Models_Albums.php';
```

some people create autoloader classes to deal with this, YMMV

Comment: You Mileage May Vary...  its been awhile since I worked on zend, so I don't have anything for you-  try loading the model static first using require_once.  If you get that working, try the Zend autoloader (in the manual) and look around for others that have created autoloaders

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your `Bootstrap` or `application.ini` needs to specify the namespace as 'Application_'.

In `Bootstrap.php`:

```
protected function _initAutoloader()
{
    $autoloader = new Zend_Application_Module_Autoloader(array(
        'basePath' => APPLICATION_PATH,
        'namespace' => 'Kwis_',
    ));
    return $autoloader;
}
```

Alernatively, in `configs/application.ini`:

```
appnamespace = "Application_"
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also extend Zend_Controller_Action and add a method like this:

```
protected $_tables = array();

protected function _getTable($table)
{
    if (false === array_key_exists($table, $this->_tables)) {
        require_once(APPLICATION_PATH.'/modules/'.$this->_request->getModuleName().'/models/'.$table.'.php');
        $this->_tables[$table] = new $table();
    }
    return $this->_tables[$table];
}
```